# WebSocket connection to 'ws://node02.myqtthub.com:8080/mqtt' failed:

Tags: html, websocket, mqtt

I'm trying to connect my webpage to a mqtt broker I recently created for a project but I keep getting the same message error in the console when I inspect the page:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://node02.myqtthub.com:8080/mqtt' failed

Here is the code I'm using for my webpage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.jpeg">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.jpeg">
    <title>NeuroGlov</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.2/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style>
      #resultado {
        font-weight:  bold;
        font-size:  1.2rem;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <main>
      <div class="px-4 py-2 my-2 text-center border-bottom">
        <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-2" src="LogotipoV2-Simple.jpeg" alt="" width="80" height="80">
        <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Traductor de Lenguaje de Señas</h1>
        <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
          <p class="lead mb-0">Predicción de una red neuronal usando Tensorflow.js</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="b-example-divider"></div>

      <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <form>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="voltaje_1" class="form-label">Dedo 1: <span id="lbl-voltaje_1">voltaje_1</span></label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="voltaje_1" min="-200" max="200" onchange="cambiarCelsius();">
                <div class="form-text">Dedo Pulgar</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="voltaje_2" class="form-label">Dedo 2: <span id="lbl-voltaje_2">voltaje_2</span></label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="voltaje_2" min="-200" max="200" onchange="cambiarCelsius();">
                <div class="form-text">Dedo índice</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="voltaje_3" class="form-label">Dedo 3: <span id="lbl-voltaje_3">voltaje_3</span></label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="voltaje_3" min="-200" max="200" onchange="cambiarCelsius();">
                <div class="form-text">Dedo medio</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="voltaje_4" class="form-label">Dedo 4: <span id="lbl-voltaje_4">voltaje_4</span></label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="voltaje_4" min="-200" max="200" onchange="cambiarCelsius();">
                <div class="form-text">Dedo anular</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="voltaje_5" class="form-label">Dedo 5: <span id="lbl-voltaje_5">voltaje_5</span></label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="voltaje_5" min="-200" max="200" onchange="cambiarCelsius();">
                <div class="form-text">Dedo meñique</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="voltaje_6" class="form-label">ax: <span id="lbl-voltaje_6">voltaje_6</span></label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="voltaje_6" min="-200" max="200" onchange="cambiarCelsius();">
                <div class="form-text">ax</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="voltaje_7" class="form-label">ay: <span id="lbl-voltaje_7">voltaje_7</span></label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="voltaje_7" min="-200" max="200" onchange="cambiarCelsius();">
                <div class="form-text">ay</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="voltaje_8" class="form-label">az: <span id="lbl-voltaje_8">voltaje_8</span></label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="voltaje_8" min="-200" max="200" onchange="cambiarCelsius();">
                <div class="form-text">az</div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="resultado" class="form-label">Resultado</label>
                <div id="resultado">
                  Aquí se mostrará la traducción de la señal
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </main>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var modelo = null;
      var audio = document.getElementById("mi-audio");
      var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      utterance.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(function(voice) {
      return voice.name === 'Google US English';
      });

      // Función para establecer la conexión MQTT y suscribirse a los temas
      function conectarMQTT() {
        // URL y puerto del broker MQTT
        var brokerUrl = 'node02.myqtthub.com';
        var brokerPort = 8080;

        // Cliente MQTT
        var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(brokerUrl, brokerPort, 'gestos_client');

        // Configurar los callbacks del cliente MQTT
        client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
        client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

        // Conectar al broker MQTT
        client.connect({
          onSuccess: onConnect,
          onFailure: onFailure,
          userName: 'jordandelgado',
          password: 'bryanysebas'
        });

        // Callback cuando se establece la conexión MQTT
        function onConnect() {
          console.log('Conectado al broker MQTT');
          // Suscribirse a los temas necesarios
          client.subscribe('voltaje_1');
          client.subscribe('voltaje_2');
          client.subscribe('voltaje_3');
          client.subscribe('voltaje_4');
          client.subscribe('voltaje_5');
          client.subscribe('voltaje_6');
          client.subscribe('voltaje_7');
          client.subscribe('voltaje_8');
        }

        // Callback en caso de fallo al conectar al broker MQTT
        function onFailure(errorMessage) {
          console.log('Error al conectar al broker MQTT: ' + errorMessage);
        }

        // Callback cuando se pierde la conexión MQTT
        function onConnectionLost(response) {
          if (response.errorCode !== 0) {
            console.log('Conexión MQTT perdida: ' + response.errorMessage);
          }
        }

        // Callback cuando llega un mensaje MQTT
        function onMessageArrived(message) {
          // Obtener el valor del voltaje del mensaje recibido
          var voltaje = parseFloat(message.payloadString);

          // Actualizar el valor en el campo correspondiente del formulario
          if (message.topic === 'voltaje_1') {
            document.getElementById('voltaje_1').value = voltaje;
            cambiarCelsius(); // Llamar a la función para actualizar la traducción
          } else if (message.topic === 'voltaje_2') {
            document.getElementById('voltaje_2').value = voltaje;
            cambiarCelsius(); // Llamar a la función para actualizar la traducción
          } else if (message.topic === 'voltaje_3') {
            document.getElementById('voltaje_3').value = voltaje;
            cambiarCelsius(); // Llamar a la función para actualizar la traducción
          } else if (message.topic === 'voltaje_4') {
            document.getElementById('voltaje_4').value = voltaje;
            cambiarCelsius(); // Llamar a la función para actualizar la traducción
          } else if (message.topic === 'voltaje_5') {
            document.getElementById('voltaje_5').value = voltaje;
            cambiarCelsius(); // Llamar a la función para actualizar la traducción
          } else if (message.topic === 'voltaje_6') {
            document.getElementById('voltaje_6').value = voltaje;
            cambiarCelsius(); // Llamar a la función para actualizar la traducción
          } else if (message.topic === 'voltaje_7') {
            document.getElementById('voltaje_7').value = voltaje;
            cambiarCelsius(); // Llamar a la función para actualizar la traducción
          } else if (message.topic === 'voltaje_8') {
            document.getElementById('voltaje_8').value = voltaje;
            cambiarCelsius(); // Llamar a la función para actualizar la traducción
          }
        }
      }

      //Cargar modelo y establecer la conexión MQTT
      (async () => {
          console.log("Cargando modelo...");
          modelo = await tf.loadLayersModel("model.json");
          console.log("Modelo cargado...");

          // Establecer la conexión MQTT
          conectarMQTT();
      })();

      function cambiarCelsius() {
        var voltaje_1 = document.getElementById("voltaje_1").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl-voltaje_1").innerHTML = voltaje_1;
        var voltaje_2 = document.getElementById("voltaje_2").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl-voltaje_2").innerHTML = voltaje_2;
        var voltaje_3 = document.getElementById("voltaje_3").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl-voltaje_3").innerHTML = voltaje_3;
        var voltaje_4 = document.getElementById("voltaje_4").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl-voltaje_4").innerHTML = voltaje_4;
        var voltaje_5 = document.getElementById("voltaje_5").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl-voltaje_5").innerHTML = voltaje_5;
        var voltaje_6 = document.getElementById("voltaje_6").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl-voltaje_6").innerHTML = voltaje_6;
        var voltaje_7 = document.getElementById("voltaje_7").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl-voltaje_7").innerHTML = voltaje_7;
        var voltaje_8 = document.getElementById("voltaje_8").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl-voltaje_8").innerHTML = voltaje_8;
        if (modelo != null) {
          var tensor = tf.tensor2d([[parseFloat(voltaje_1), parseFloat(voltaje_2), parseFloat(voltaje_3), parseFloat(voltaje_4), parseFloat(voltaje_5), parseFloat(voltaje_6), parseFloat(voltaje_7), parseFloat(voltaje_8)]]);
          var prediccion = modelo.predict(tensor).dataSync();
          prediccion = Math.round(prediccion, 2);
          if (!isNaN(prediccion)){
            var texto = prediccion.toString();
            utterance.text = texto;
            speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
          }

          document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Traducción: " + prediccion;

        } else {
          document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Intenta de nuevo en un momento...";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried changing the port multiple times with no results.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76644911/edit) the question to include the full error from the browser console. Also include information about the page you are trying to connect from, e.g. is  the page loaded over https?

Comment: In addition to the above - are you sure your broker (`myqtthub.com`) supports websocket connections? ([this](https://support.asplhosting.com/t/websockets-support/82/12) does not look promising).